# C - 8051 Array output

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops, 8051

I am getting a very trivial but yet seemingly hard bug in my code to fix. Long story short, I have a an array that gets filled with information as I am reading values of data from a chip. This array called `data_buffer` then sends every character into the UART in a sort of hex file format for debugging purposes.

When I type the command and the characters are output into the terminal the array is spitting out null characters for spaces in which I specified there be data.

The code is as follows and I will try my best to put it in sequential order:

```
void read_256_address(void)
{
    char SFRPAGE_SAVE=SFRPAGE;
    SFRPAGE=CONFIG_PAGE;

    RFLAG=0;

    address_sum=((unsigned long)address_byte3<<16)
                +((unsigned long)address_byte2<<8)
                +((unsigned long)address_byte1);

    if(chip_byte>=0 && chip_byte<=76)
    {
        Port4=chip_byte;
        read_address_loop();
    }

    while(RFLAG==0){if(RFLAG==1){break;}}

    SFRPAGE=SFRPAGE_SAVE;
}

void read_address_loop(void)
{
    unsigned long int i=14;

    char SFRPAGE_SAVE=SFRPAGE;
    SFRPAGE=CONFIG_PAGE;

    RFLAG=0;

    if(command_byte==0x82)
    {
        write_P4();
  for(next_address=address_sum;next_address<(address_sum+256);next_address++)
        {
            output_address();
            read_op();
            hex_data=data_read;
            HEXtoASC();
            data_buffer[i]=msb;i++;
            data_buffer[i]=lsb;i++;
            data_buffer[i]=' ';i++;
            if(next_address+=15){format_data_dump();}
        }
   }

void output_data(void)
{
    unsigned char i;

    for(i=0;i<65;i++)
    {
        send_byte(data_buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

I apologize for the indention on the `for loop` but that was due to formatting. It should be aligned with the `write_P4();` code above it. When the code above runs it outputs the format wanted but not the values, such as:

```
M82 1B 104560 FF ****null char for remaining indices**** 0x0D 0x0A
M82 1B 104560 FF FF ****null char for remaining indices**** 0x0D 0x0A
M82 1B 104560 FF FF FF ****null char for remaining indices**** 0x0D 0x0A
```

What I am expecting to see is below:

```
M82 1B 1040560 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 0x0D 0x0A
M82 1B 1040570 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 0x0D 0x0A
.
.
.
M82 1B 1040650 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 0x0D 0x0A
```

Could someone please give me some insight as to why this may be happening? It seems like the buffer is increasing in length after each iteration of the entire buffer not the same length every time.

Comment: `else if(command_byte==0x82)` There is no natching `if` (you probably made a cut&paste error somewhere)

Comment: @wildplasser I apologize for that statement. There is a matching `if` statement in my actual code that goes before it. I just excluded it for purposes of condensing my code in the question. I can see how this would cause confusion.

Comment: What was your intention with `if (next_address+=15)` ? `next_address += 15` adds `15`, but this always evaluates to `true`, and it's confusing when you change the `for` loop variable at two places. Did you mean something like `next_address % 16 == 15`? I would say the code is rather convoluted for what it does. How about you 1) read the data into an array of a certain length in one function, and then 2) dump the contents of an array into a hex string in a second function? That would be much easier to test (and reason about) than this.

Comment: @Groo my intention was for the `for` loop to increment `next_address` 15 times and when the 15th time came around then that would fill up the `data_buffer` and send it out to the terminal. So I should see 16 rows with data from 16 addresses. Which is what I got but I am getting `null char` instead of `FF`. I hope that makes sense. I may have explained that all over the place ha

Comment: @Groo I have not tried the modulus operation yet. Brb with outcome

Comment: In that case, there's a mistake, because `next_address += 15` increases `next_address` by `15` in each iteration. `next_address % 16` will be 0 for `0`, `16`, `32`, etc., so I presumed you will want to dump on the `15th` index.

Comment: @Groo yes! Exactly! I was using the `if` statement to check if `next_address` had been incremented 15 times, and if so jump to the subroutine where it would load the rest of the buffer with values that I hardwired into it.

Comment: @Groo `next_address%16==0` is working to a degree. I assume this must be the way my code is formatted.

Comment: Well, `i` variable is also suspicious. You initialize it to `14` (I am presuming `output_address` then writes to these first `14` bytes, but you haven't posted it), but you never reset it back after dumping a line. As I said, I would ditch this and split it into several simple functions which don't operate on shared state, to make it easier to test each function separately.

Comment: You are right I never initialize it back down to 14. I do have a function in which the first 14 indexes are loaded into the buffer. This routine is meant to load indexes 14-62 then output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not find your issue, but let me put some comments on what I see in your code for you to ponder.  Comments will appears above code in question:

```
void read_256_address(void)
{
    char SFRPAGE_SAVE=SFRPAGE;
    SFRPAGE=CONFIG_PAGE;

    RFLAG=0;
```

Assuming address sum is at least 32-bits in size?

```
    address_sum=((unsigned long)address_byte3<<16)
                +((unsigned long)address_byte2<<8)
                +((unsigned long)address_byte1);
```

If `chip_bytes` is unsigned, the 0 check is not needed

```
    if(chip_byte>=0 && chip_byte<=76)
    {
        Port4=chip_byte;
        read_address_loop();
    }
```

I pray that `RFLAG` is `volatile` here otherwise chaos.  On a threaded system, a yield or the like would be good here instead of spinning.

```
    while(RFLAG==0){if(RFLAG==1){break;}}

    SFRPAGE=SFRPAGE_SAVE;
}

void read_address_loop(void)
{
```

Very magical 14 and i as a non-index is also not a good idea (oh, I see - used later for indexing.)

```
    unsigned long int i=14;

    char SFRPAGE_SAVE=SFRPAGE;
    SFRPAGE=CONFIG_PAGE;

    RFLAG=0;

    if(command_byte==0x82)
    {
        write_P4();
```

If address_sum is close to the size of its type, this could loop forever.

```
        for(next_address=address_sum;
            next_address<(address_sum+256);
            next_address++)
        {
            output_address();
            read_op();
            hex_data=data_read;
            HEXtoASC();
```

Consider placing the ++ on the i in the indexing

```
            data_buffer[i]=msb;i++;
            data_buffer[i]=lsb;i++;
```

A space for the 3rd byte?  That is interesting - guessing this is the part where you are getting the `NUL` values instead.  Perhaps double check your converter to see if it is helping you by converting spaces to 0.

```
            data_buffer[i]=' ';i++;
```

Consider using `next_address & 0x0f` if you are checking for 0 in low nibble, the plus 15 is very strange.  Do you perhaps mean plus 16?

```
            if(next_address+=15){format_data_dump();}
        }
   }

void output_data(void)
{
    unsigned char i;
```

Magical 65 size again - consider sizeof() the array or checking for end via another method.

```
    for(i=0;i<65;i++)
    {
        send_byte(data_buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

Of all the stuff I call out above, the if check with the +=15 is the area that seems the most troubling.  Again, I don't know if anything of what I have catches your issue, but it is worth looking at them deeper to be sure.

Comment: `address_sum` is not 8 bytes wide but it was 5 bytes wide & I don't know of a data type that is 6 bytes wide. `chip_byte` is unsigned so the check is mainly for sanity on my part. I am not familiar with the `volatile` type so I will look in on that. Address sum will never go beyond 0x140000 (declared variable that prevent that). I will place the `++` to clean it up. I assumed that if I hardwired the character into that index I wouldn't need to convert? I am checking to see if `next_address` has been incremented 15 times so I can dump it out into the terminal. Like checking for a `NULL` char?

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions! Just had a couple more questions for ya

Comment: `address_sum` then is a non-standard type?  That means your compiler must be doing some magic to make the math work on your system.  `volatile` tells your compiler to not optimize your loop - to always read the value in, even though it appears it will never change.  It's very common in embedded coding.  And if you are checking to see if `next_address` has been incremented 15 times, then consider a separate counter.  Increment it every loop, if == 15, reset to 0 and dump.  Much cleaner as what you have now will not really do that at all.

Comment: I got it to work! Actually ended up splitting a couple of the repeating code into separate subroutines for purposes of cleaning up and readability. It works fine now! appreciate the help

Comment: Glad to hear it!